# Split column using awk or sed

Tags: bash, perl, unix, awk, sed

I have a file containing  the following text.

> dog
>   aa  6469
>   bb  5946
>   cc  715
>
> cat
>   aa  5692
>
> Bird
>   aa  3056
>   bb  2893
>   cc  1399
>   dd  33

I need the following output:

> > A-Z   ,aa ,bb,    cc, dd
> >     dog,    6469,   5946    ,715,   0
> >     cat ,5692,  0,  0,  0
> >     Bird    ,3056,  2893,   1399,   33

I tried:
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="," RS=
But is not giving the format I need.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cris

Comment: You tried `awk '{$1=$1}1'`? Is that supposed to be funny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -v OFS=, 'NF==1 {h[++c]=$1} 
              NF==2 {v[c,$1]=$2; ks[$1]} 
              END   {printf "%s", "A-Z"; 
                     for(k in ks) printf "%s", OFS k; 
                     print ""; 
                     for(i=1;i<=c;i++) 
                       {printf "%s", h[i]; 
                        for(k in ks) printf "%s", OFS v[i,k]+0; 
                        print ""}}' file'
```

order of the columns will be random.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

With Perl

```
perl -00 -nE'
    ($t, %p) = split /[\n\s]/; $h{$t} = {%p};     # Top line, Pairs on lines
    $o{$t} = ++$c;                                # remember Order
    %k = map { $_, 1} keys %p;                    # find full set of subKeys
    }{                                            # END block starts
    say join ",", "A-Z", sort keys %k;
    for $t (sort { $o{$a} <=> $o{$b} } keys %h) { 
        say join ",", $k, map { ($h{$k}{$_} // 0) } sort keys %k;
    }
' data.txt
```

prints, in the original order

```
A-Z,aa,bb,cc,dd
dog,6469,5946,715,0
cat,5692,0,0,0
Bird,3056,2893,1399,33
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sed solution, which works on your input, but requires that you know the column names in advance and that the column names are given as sorted full ranges starting with the first column name (so nothing like *aa, cc* or *bb, aa* or *bb, cc*) and that every paragraph is followed by one empty line. You would also need to adjust the script if you don't have exactly four numeric columns:

`echo 'A-Z, aa, bb, cc, dd';sed -e '/./{s/.* //;H;d};x;s/\n/, /g;s/, //;s/$/, 0, 0, 0, 0/;:a;s/,[^,]*//5;ta' file`

If you need to look up the sed commands, you can look at `info sed`, especially *3.5 Less Frequently-Used Commands*.